# Possible to mix JSX and regular object for routes in React Router?

Tags: react-router, reactjs

With React Router, I see [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md) that I can define my routes as either JSX or just a normal object. I have a use case where I would like to share `settingsRoutes` with another part of my application as a normal object but still use JSX for the other routes. The second code block is what I was like to do. Is this mixing of JSX and objects possible with react router??

```js
const settingsRoutes = [{
  path: 'settings',
  component: Settings,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'info',
      component: SettingsInfo
    }
  ]
}]

module.exports = settingsRoutes
```

```js
var settingsRoutes = require('settingsRoutes')

<Route path='/' component={ Container }>
  <Route path='register' component={ Register } />
  <Route path='signin' component={ Signin } />
  <Route path='signout' component={ Signout } } />
  { settingsRoutes }
</Route>
```

Comment: It should be possible as long as `{ settingsRoutes }` evaluates to valid JSX/HTML which I don't think is happening right now based on your first code block.

Comment: did you try `<Route {…settingsRoute} />` or `{settingsRoutes.map(route => <Route {…route} />)}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```js
<Route path='/' component={ Container }>
  <Route path='register' component={ Register } />
  <Route path='signin' component={ Signin } />
  <Route path='signout' component={ Signout } } />
  <Route childRoutes={settingsRoutes} />
</Route>
```